# How to create comparing sql database, with combobox and textbox, aka pre-pass protected from

Tags: c#

Hello I want to create a first form with pass protected proceeding. So I have a SQL database table `Users` with columns `id`, `name` (you see it in combobox) and `password`.

Now I want if I choose from combobox user name and enter right password into textbox below (matching with the one in database) when I press button proceed close this form and go on 2nd.

I don't know how to match the password in the textbox and the database.

Picture of my form: [Picture](http://prntscr.com/23gxgr)

This is my code:

```
private void usersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Validate();
   this.usersBindingSource.EndEdit();
   this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.usersDataSet);
}

private void Pass_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'usersDataSet.Users' table. 
   //       You can move, or remove it, as needed.
   this.usersTableAdapter.Fill(this.usersDataSet.Users);
}

private void BtnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (ComboIme.SelectedValue == "Matjaz Pecavar") 
   { 
     // passtxt.Text = ;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you are asking is that you want to put in a password and then look up in a sql database whether the password/name combo is a match.

Assume you have a database with two columns [name] and [password]
you can query the password of the name using a sql query which you can configure using the datasource designer.

```
Select [password]
from dbo.users 
where [name] = @myname
```

this should return just one value, so then check to see if the value returned is a match to the value in the textbox

```
string pword = tableadaptermanager.getpassword(usernamebox1.text).tostring();
if (pword == passwordbox1.text)
{
    do something useful
{
```

Hope that helps. Cheers.

Comment: What about this one? But still have errors.

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Bojan\Desktop\Programiranje\School\Kartice\Kartice\Users.mdf");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Ime_Priimek = '" & ComboIme.SelectedIndex & "' AND [Password] = '" & passtxt.Text & "' ", con);
            
          con.Open();
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //  If the record can be queried, it means passing verification, then open another form.

Comment: if ((sdr.Read() == true))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The user is valid!");
            Matjaz.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password!");
        }

Comment: Not sure about why that one has errors but i suspect you can simplify it a bunch by using the datasource designer and passing arguments in the places that you need them. for instance, you can make a function like "FILL(table1,ComboIme.SelectedIndex,passtxt.Text)